# Convert number to current Euro

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to learn it, so for this question, I will start with an example:

I have a table like this already done in MySQL (manually done).

**Tables_Name** = Product

| Product | Product_Price |
| --- | --- |
| HAT | 20.00 |
| BELT | 15.00 |

Now, I'm trying (by coding) to convert the 20's ans 15's into:

| Product | Product_Price |
| --- | --- |
| HAT | 20.00 € |
| BELT | 15.00 € |

I've seen a lot of codes to do the conversion, such like:

> MODIFY COLUMN Product_Price VARCHAR(18,2)
> SELECT FORMAT(Product_Price,'c','en-US');

But this always give me an error.

Can someone come up with a code that will modify all the "datatypes" in the column Product_Price into €'s values?

I'm trying to covert the values to euros.

Comment: What should be the purpose to do this? I think that's an incorrect idea. If you want to set a curreny, better add a column currency id which references to a table "currencies". Thus, different rows can get a different currency joining the two tables and concat price and currency symbol. This way, you could even add an information whether to put the currency symbol before or after the price to be more flexible.

Comment: Likewise confused - if you want to add a currency symbol to a column that column has to be a string and then of course you would not be able to use it in arithmetic without removing the currency symbol and casting..

Comment: Don't do that in the first place. Using a text field to store prices or any other numeric value is a critical error. You have no idea to know what's stored in there, whether the application saved numbers with dots or commas as separators. It's bugs like these that cause end up in the news as `Pensioner asked to pay $1M water bill`

Comment: Besides, if you really care about currencies, you *want* the currency code as a separate column so you can eg join with an exchange rate table to easily convert from one currency to another. That's impossible if you store just a currency symbol in a text field.

Comment: Euros normally have a comma decimal separator is that what you mean by convert to euros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest not saving the values with the `€` symbol, because you have to use a string column which will require to be transformed again into numbers datatype if you would make calculations in the future.

You simple add the symbol on your select statement as follows:

```
select Product,
       concat(Product_Price,' €') as Product_Price
from Product;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/YCd2bkM8